# Removing a node with left and right subtrees from BST with duplicates

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

The [DSA book](http://dotnetslackers.com/projects/Data-Structures-And-Algorithms/) describes this case of deletion of a node from the binary search tree:

"4. the value to remove has both a left and right subtree in which case we
promote the largest value in the left subtree."

Let's say, we have the following (I tried to make it look like a tree):

```
      7
  6       8
5   6       8
```

If we remove root (7), it says we should put 6 to its place. Now it would look like that (it just doesn't feel right):

```
      6
  6       8
5           8
```

Now 6 is a left node of 6. But it shouldn't, right (the values on the left should be less)? So, I guess my questions would be: is it okay to have such cases?  If such cases are acceptable, is there a name for that? Or should we choose some other nodes to substitute the deleted one?

Comment: generally, you cannot have the same value in a BST. Its a set of *unique* keys (which are also the values in this case)

Comment: @clcto The same page of this book says: "Of course in a BST a value may occur more than once. In such a case the first occurrence of that value in the BST will be removed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your assumption that all "equal" values be in the right sub-tree? If so, you can always replace the node with the smallest value in it's right sub-tree. If they can be on either side then you don't have a problem.